# Can electron webview transform mouse event to touch event?

Tags: electron

I want to simulate a mobile device in desktop environment. I can't find a argument to transform mouse event to touch event.

How can I approach this job? Any hint will be great. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 5):

I think I figured it out. Dev environment:

- node 7.4.0
- Chromium 54.0.2840.101
- Electron 1.5.1

```
    const app = electron.app 
    const BrowserWindow = electron.BrowserWindow

    let mainWindow;
    function createWindow() {

      mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1024,
        height: 768,
        frame: false,
        x: -1920,
        y: 0,
        autoHideMenuBar: true,
        icon: 'assets/icons/win/app-win-icon.ico'
      });

      try {
        // works with 1.1 too
        mainWindow.webContents.debugger.attach('1.2')
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('Debugger attach failed: ', err)
      }

      const isDebuggerAttached = mainWindow.webContents.debugger.isAttached()
      console.log('debugger attached? ', isDebuggerAttached)

      mainWindow.webContents.debugger.on('detach', (event, reason) => {
        console.log('Debugger detached due to: ', reason)
      });

      // This is where the magic happens!
      mainWindow.webContents.debugger.sendCommand('Emulation.setTouchEmulationEnabled', {
        enabled: true,
        configuration: 'mobile',
      });

      mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true,
        show: false,
        backgroundColor: '#8e24aa ',
      }));

      // Show the mainwindow when it is loaded and ready to show
      mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
          mainWindow.show()
      })
    }

    // Listen for app to be ready
    app.on('ready', createWindow);
```

Comment: Wowzer, thanks - this works well. Have you deployed anything with this? Is it reliable enough?

Comment: I made a little to-do list app which runs on a pos machine for a company and it has been working in production with no issues for over a month. They loved how scrolling works

Comment: It has changed, now it's `mainWindow.webContents.debugger.sendCommand("Emulation.setEmitTouchEventsForMouse", {
        enabled: true
    });`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [Electron github issue](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8125) or this [Atom Discussion](https://discuss.atom.io/t/touch-events-and-scrolling/36575/7) for ideas on how to get the touch working with Electron.

As far as how to approach it, I would look through the [mouse events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) and [touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events) and just wire up a function that combines the Electron api and the relevant web api for mouse/touch.

Comment: yeah. I saw that github issue too. I try to wire up mouse and touch event. But sadly, Electron doesn't support touch event with ```sendInputEvent``` function.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [`web-contents`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/web-contents.md#contentsopendevtoolsoptions) API, the only thing you can do is to open the dev tools with:

```
// win being a BrowserWindow object
win.webContents.openDevTools();
```

Then you will have to manually click on the responsive tools (the smartphone icon), and you will get into the mode you want.

But I am afraid there is no way to do it programatically. Mostly because it is considered as a development tool, and not a browser feature, so you will have the toolbar at the top and all these things. Not really something you want on Production.

Comment: This is not what I looking for. But thanks all the same.

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you really want. D you mean like the Chrome Devtools when you click on the responsive tools and it "transforms" your page like if it was a smartphone, and your events are considered "touch" events?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm talking about . But Electron doesn't have that kind of  api. So I simply give up now.

Comment: I updated my answer then, just in case someone needs it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use Microsoft Windows Simulator. You need to install Visual Studio 2019 with Universal Windows Platform development then run the simulator through:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Simulator\16.0\Microsoft.Windows.Simulator.exe
```

I tested my electron app that also needs to run well both on touchscreen devices and devices without touch screen using this and it works really well to simulate touchscreen devices.

[image]

Do not forget to switch to touchscreen input on the right side of the panel, otherwise, the default input will simulate a mouse pointer.